# How to get executing server name or address with Selenium Server 2.20

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When working with Selenium Server, it would be very useful to log the name of the machine that actually does the execution of the selenium script. Is it possible to get that information?

I am working with C# bindings, but answer in any language would do fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should know where the Selenium Server is running.

### This is Java Code :

we have straight method for this in `HttpCommandExecutor` class, `getAddressOfRemoteServer()`

code for Firefox :

```java
RemoteWebDriver rcw = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://serveraddress:portnumber/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox())
```

so if you have an instance of `RemoteWebDriver`

### `rcw.getCommandExecutor().getAddressOfRemoteServer()`

code for IE :

Same as Above OR for Local

### `((HttpCommandExecutor)(new InternetExplorerDriver().getCommandExecutor())).getAddressOfRemoteServer();`

Comment: Doesn't this return the address of the hub rather than the node? i.e. in your example it will return "http://serveraddress:portnumber/wd/hub"

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do this in Grid.

Please refer to this blog post of mine to learn how to find out the node ip and port to which the test was routed to.

Blog post : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/where-did-my-test-run/

In a nutshell, here's what you need to do (The blog I shared has elaborate explanation and required code )

- Get the session id from webdriver via Webdriver.getSessionId()
- You then append the session id obtained from the previous step to the URL http://localhost:4444/grid/api/testsession?session= (replace `localhost` with the actual Grid IP/host and replace `4444` with the port on which grid is listening to) and trigger a POST call.
- From the JSON response you parse the value of attribute `proxyId` as a URL and extract out the IP and port from it.