# Find which node my selenium-grid remote driver is running on?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I obtain a RemoteWebDriver from the hub as follows:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver( 
                                      new URL("http://whatever:4444/wd/hub"),
                                      DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer() );
```

Is there a way to programatically find out which node in the grid the remote driver is running on?

I want to log this in an effort to track down intermittent test failures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get executing server name or address with Selenium Server 2.20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771932/how-to-get-executing-server-name-or-address-with-selenium-server-2-20)

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate question is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to this blog post of mine to learn how to find out the node ip and port to which the test was routed to.

Blog post : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/where-did-my-test-run/

In a nutshell, here's what you need to do (The blog I shared has elaborate explanation and required code )

- Get the session id from webdriver via Webdriver.getSessionId()
- You then append the session id obtained from the previous step to the URL http://localhost:4444/grid/api/testsession?session= (replace `localhost` with the actual Grid IP/host and replace `4444` with the port on which grid is listening to) and trigger a POST call.
- From the JSON response you parse the value of attribute `proxyId` as a URL and extract out the IP and port from it.

This is now available for ready consumption via the library [talk2grid](https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/talk2grid) that I built.